# Fortran77 routine with multi CPU?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, intel-parallel-studio

I would like to know if it's possible to run a program written in fortran, which is quite "heavy", exploiting all the 24 threads of the CPUs.

I am using intel parallel studio XE 2011 and the routine is written in fortran 77.

Comment: It's certainly possible and you should direct your researches, in the first instance, towards 'OpenMP'.

Comment: Sorry for reply late on this. I figured out my code had some problems, now I am ready to try to parallelize it.
I was reading [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f77_src/openmp/openmp.html) and [here](https://www.ncsu.edu/hpc/Courses/7shared.html) and [here](http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/nmm1/openmp/Notes/notes_2.pdf).
I am not an expert in programming, I am just a mechanical engineer and I have learnt the fortran basis recently, so sorry if what I say it's just a bullshit.
I have understand that it's possible to parallelize loops like DO, FOR, by adding the "pragmas". It's only that?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's possible. There's quite some ways to go about this, but:

What I'm used to is having your "system logic" in a more versatile logic that directly supports things like pthreads or boost threads etc; most likely something like C or C++, and then spawning different threads for different parts of your calculation or parallelizable data parts, etc. Notice that modern compilers can generate binaries from fortran that adhere to normal C calling conventions, so that calling fortran functions doesn't have more overhead than calling other C, C++, ... functions. You should make damn sure not to modify global state in your fortran functions, though!

There's no parallelization framework for fortran77 that I would be aware of; there are a [few in existence](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Parallelization), but as far as I can tell they depend on language features that weren't there in F77. As @HighPerformanceMark pointed out, OpenMP could very well work with the intel compilers.

Comment: OpenMP doesn't depend on any features added to Fortran after the '77 standard.

Comment: ah right; I just didn't know intel fortran included openMP support!

Comment: It has supported OpenMP more or less since the time OpenMP appeared even before being acquired by Intel. And you can also call pthreads. People used to use platform specific libraries before OpenMP.

Comment: *As @HighPerformanceMark pointed out, OpenMP could very well work with the intel compilers.*  Not really, my point is implementation independent.  And most current Fortran compilers can cope with OpenMP.